# Using ngFor and ngFormControl

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am trying to generate a checkboxes based on an array of possible checkbox

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let category of Categories" >
      <input type="checkbox" name={{category}}
      [ngFormControl]="myForm.controls[{{category}}]"> {{category}}
  </div>
```

However this does not work as it seems that the `{{category}}` for the `ngFormControl` is not being replaced with the appropriate value.

The error I get is

> Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 27 in
>   [myForm.controls['{{category}}']] in Fees@46:4 ("ow"
>   *ngFor="let category of Categories" >
>       ][ngFormControl]="myForm.controls['{{category}}']"> {{category}}

Answer (score 1):

Just a typo, replace:

```
*ngFor="let category of Cateories"
```

by:

```
*ngFor="let category of Categories"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, (un)fortunately I made the same mistake when I declared Cate(g)ories so that didnt solve the problem.

Comment: sorry to hear that. The error you get is related to [ngFormControl], which should receive a string, rather than an interpolation. Do you have a plunker of the issue, by any chance?

Comment: I unfortunately do not have a plunker of the issue,  and the  "{{myForm.controls[category]}}" seems to not work either.